# anacondaでのccxtインストール失敗

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, anaconda3

https://note.mu/zephel01/n/n985c2fe0b6c6
こちらのサイトを参考にwindowsでccxtをインストールしようと試みているのですが
下記エラーで行き詰まっています。
環境はwindows8.1にanaconda3です。

試したこと

- lru-dictがどうやら失敗しているようなので単品でインストール→同じエラー
- 「fatal error C1083: include ファイルを開けません。'io.h':No such file or directory」 原因わかららず。権限はあるもののio.hは存在しない→VS2017インストール
- pipアップデート

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
  Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
Installing collected packages: cchardet, pycares, aiodns, lru-dict, web3, ccxt
  Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\dq\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DQ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-
c4afsz_d\\lru-dict\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f
.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" i
nstall --record C:\Users\DQ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yi6dtr7k\install-recor
d.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'lru' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\
14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\user
s\dq\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\dq\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include
" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC
\14.15.26726\include" /Tclru.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\lru.obj
    lru.c
    c:\users\dq\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: include フ
ァイルを開けません。'io.h':No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Comm
unity\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit
 status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\dq\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__f
ile__='C:\\Users\\DQ\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c4afsz_d\\lru-dict\\setu
p.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users
\DQ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yi6dtr7k\install-record.txt --single-version-e
xternally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\DQ\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\pip-install-c4afsz_d\lru-dict\
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/harmyhobberhead/items/7b34b8219436ebe27aca

Answer (score 1):

このエラーは、`Visual Studio`で`io.h`というライブラリーがincludeできないために発生したものです。初心者がそれを修正するのは難しいので、`lru-dict`のインストールを`pip`ではなく、`conda`の方で`lru-dict`のバイナリーの[パッケージ](https://anaconda.org/quantopian/lru-dict)をインストールすればいいのではないでしょうか。

```
conda install -c quantopian lru-dict
```

Comment: 無事インストールできました。こんなことで3日ほど悩んでおりました。ありがとうございます。